# Multiple resultset from mariadb procedure

Tags: mariadb, phpmyadmin

I am trying to return multiple resultsets from (phpmyadmin) mariadb procedure but am failing. For example I have two tables Entities and Relations and for a test I created a procedure to select everything from both tables:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST_FOO;

DELIMITER &&

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_FOO()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Entities;
    SELECT * FROM Relations;
END &&
DELIMITER ;

CALL TEST_FOO();
```

When I run this query I get an error:

> Error
>
> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> ```
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> ```
>
> SQL query: Copy Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

What am I missing? It says something about foreign key checks and in phpmyadmin there is a checkbox with the same name and it doesnt matter if I check it or not.

Comment: procedures have no resultset, can't you join both tables that would work

Comment: @nbk These tables have different columns and different number of them.
I've read that you can select multiple tables in mysql so I assumed it is also possible somehow with mariadb.

Comment: a join  combines two tables , by putting them horizontally together, s taht yoiu become one large table as result set

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php

Comment: yes but php has nothing to do with sql, so while php or python works, it doesn't mean that it will work in sql

Comment: Why I want to avoid using join and like is consider a case where Relation contains multiple columns that reference (foreign key) to Entities (id column). Using join would give me a table that is 2x, 3x, 5x bigger then the useful information it contains.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with phpmyadmin.

Your procedure works fine, as far as I can tell, when running it in the `mariadb` command-line client. So the workaround is to not use phpmyadmin for this.